# cat and Pipe to Run Command Won't Take Two Arguments

Tags: command-line, cat

I have been using this command:

```
cat urls.txt | xargs -n 1 -P 10 wget -q
```

to download text files of URLs. This worked fine when my URL file was like:

```
http://domain1.com/page.html
http://domain2.com/page.html
http://domain3.com/page.html
```

However I now need to download text files of URLs and post data, like:

```
--post-data '1=1' http://domain1.com/page.html
--post-data '1=1' http://domain2.com/page.html
--post-data '1=1' http://domain3.com/page.html
```

When using the above cat command it tries to download the URL and then the post data as a URL. e.g. in the above example, it would download http://domain1.com/page.html and then try and download --post-data 1=1, then http://domain2.com/page.html and so on.

Is there anyway to get cat to send each line of the URLs files only?

**Update**: I've found that by adding an escape to the space like:

```
--post-data '1=1'\ http://domain1.com/page.html
```

is making it be treated as one url, but the -- appear to be stripped from the --post-data argument.

Comment: Try `-L 1` instead of `-n 1`. This will run wget once for each line of input rather than once for each word of input.

Comment: Thank you Mark Plotnick, that has done the trick. Feel free to post the answer if you would like the rep. from this post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make `xargs` run your command once for each line of input, give it the `-L 1` option (and remove the `-n 1` option, since they are mutually exclusive). The [standards document for xargs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/xargs.html) says this:

```
-L number
The utility shall be executed for each non-empty number lines of arguments
from standard input. A line is considered to end with the first <newline>
unless the last character of the line is a <blank>; a trailing <blank>
signals continuation to the next non-empty line, inclusive.
```

Answer (score 1):

Open the terminal and run:

```
cat urls.txt | sed "s/[\"\<\>' \t\(\);]/\n/g" | grep "http://" | sort -u | xargs -n 1 -P 10 wget -q
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't *need* `xargs`,you can do this with a simple bash loop Either keep your URLs as  a simple list and add the options directly to `wget`:

```
while IFS= read -r url; do wget --post-data '1=1' "$url"; done < urls.txt
```

or include them in the file and pass them to `wget`:

```
while IFS= read -r url; do wget "$url"; done < urls.txt
```